# Rotation triggers Textwatcher/afterTextchanged. Does OnfocusChange avoid it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, textwatcher

I'm a newbie.
 In my fragments I have several Edittext.
 I use Textwatcher / afterTextchanged to read inputs and send them to Activity.
 Just rotating the device, Textwatcher trigger even if Edittexts are empty.
Why?
 This make execution of code inside mListener to comunicate with Activity.
How to avoid it?
So that only if something has been really input Textwatcher triggers and so the code inside afterTextchanged?
Maybe using OnFocusChange could help me?
Please explain me why checking if input is different from null, simply doesn't work and the code has been executed anyway!

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String enteredValue  = s.toString();
    if(enteredValue != null )
    {
       // whatever I want
    }
}
```

I have solved this problem using this control:

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String text = editable.toString();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.input_manifestazione:
                if(text.length() > 0 ){
                    mListener.onFragmentInteraction00(text);
                }
                break;
```